# Difference between TileWMS and WMTS in openlayers 3?

Tags: openlayers-3

Whats the difference between ol.source.TileWMS and ol.source.WMTS? As of i know if tiled = true is added in WMS url both will return Tiled Images in openlayers 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: off-topic, must be send to gis.stackexchange

Answer (score 3):

The OpenLayers documentation says:

> An ol.source.TileWMS loads tile data from WMS servers.
>   An ol.source.WMTS loads tile data from WMTS servers.

A WMS serves images which are generated on-the-fly, whilst a WMTS serves tiles which are pre-rendered and cached.
The advantage of the latter is that you achieve better performance, but it also requires storage space.

Check out this answer also:
[Difference between WMTS and WMS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53011/difference-between-a-wmts-and-a-wms)

Comment: i know the difference between WMS and WMTS. But i dontknow whtas the difference between TileWMS and WMTS used in openlayers.

Comment: WMS and WMTS services are organized slightly differently and accept different input parameters, and the two ol.sources are adapted to these differences. For instance, ol.source.WMS has 'params' where you specify 'LAYERS=' and ol.source.WMTS has an own 'layers' property.